# how to add \n before 4th pipe and after last double Quotes in a file in unix

Tags: file, unix, sed

I have a line in a file. like:

- 1|4|ab|"abnchf "dnvjnkjf" fdvjnfkjnv" 2|12|df|"dskfnkfv "A"

I want to break the into two rows by adding \n at before 4th pipe and after last double quotes.

it should be like:

- 1|4|ab|"abnchf "dnvjnkjf" fdvjnfkjnv"

  2|12|df|"dskfnkfv "A"

i have tried sed command but its not working

```
sed 's/\(|[^|]*\)(|[^|]*\)(|[^|]*\)|/\1\n|/g'
```

Comment: @AndrewMairose That is only true for a POSIX ERE and Perl-like regex. In a BRE POSIX pattern, `|` matches a literal `|` char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's/\([^|]*|\)\{3\}[^|]* /&\n/' file > newfile
```

See the [online demo](http://ttps://ideone.com/OEoqaV)

**Details**

- `\([^|]*|\)\{3\}` - three consecutve occurrences of

  - `[^|]*` - 0+ chars other than `|`
  - `|` - a pipe symbol
- `[^|]*` - 0+ chars other than `|`
- - a space

The replacement pattern is `&\n`, the whole match (`&`) and a newline (`\n`).

The replacement is only done once per line since I removed the `g` option.

To avoid overescaping, you may use a POSIX ERE based `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/([^|]*\|){3}[^|]* /&\n/' file > newfile
```

where you do not need to escape capturing parentheses and range/interval quantifier braces (but you have to escape a literal `|` char).

Comment: can you tell me, where can i find about regex pattern in unix with good examples?

Comment: @AmitKumar You may check [Regular Expressions - The Grymoire!](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html). Also, [this site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)  can be of help, too.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^ |]*|/\n&/4' file
```

Insert a newline before the fourth field delimited by `|`.